# Pointers used as values in map corrupted after function finishes

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to store a map of `VALUE` to `Node*` but after each `addEdge`, the value for the added keys (`Node*`) changes.

One example is if I call `addEdge(u, v)`, the map shows all the data correctly within the lifetime. If another call is made to `addEdge(u, w)`, the keys `u, v` are present but the values are "corrupted"? Here's an example of the output:
[image]

Sample code:

```cpp
struct Node {
    VALUE value;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
};

class Graph {
    std::map<VALUE, Node*> nodes;
};

void Graph::addEdge(VALUE u, VALUE v) {
    Node* uNode;
    Node* vNode;

    if (nodes.count(u) == 0) {
        uNode = &Node{ u, nullptr, nullptr };
        nodes.emplace(u, uNode);
    } else {
        uNode = nodes.at(u);
    }

    if (nodes.count(v) == 0) {
        vNode = &Node{ v, nullptr, nullptr };
        nodes.emplace(v, vNode);
    } else {
        vNode = nodes.at(v);
    }

    uNode->next = vNode;
    vNode->prev = uNode;
}
```

I've tried calling `nodes.emplace` after assigning `next, prev` but it didn't fix it. Thanks!

**EDIT**
Updated addEdge:

```cpp
void addEdgeVALUE u, VALUE v) {
    Node* uNode;
    Node* vNode;
    bool isUNodePresent = true;
    bool isVNodePresent = true;

    if (nodes.count(u) == 0) {
        isUNodePresent = false;
        uNode = new Node(u, nullptr, nullptr);
    } else {
        uNode = &nodes.at(u);
    }

    if (nodes.count(v) == 0) {
        isVNodePresent = false;
        vNode = new Node(v, nullptr, nullptr);
    } else {
        vNode = &nodes.at(v);
    }

    uNode->next = vNode;
    vNode->prev = uNode;

    if (!isUNodePresent) nodes.emplace(u, *uNode);
    if (!isVNodePresent) nodes.emplace(v, *vNode);

}
```

Comment: `Node{ u, nullptr, nullptr }` creates a ***temporary*** object. It will be immediately destructed, and any pointers saved to it will be useless.

Comment: why do you store pointers in the map? They are dangling because the objects they point to are gone

Comment: I''m actually surprised that the compiler doesn't shout at you for using the pointer-to operator `&` to point to a temporary object. If it doesn't then you need to enable more warnings and treat the warnings as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not too familar with pointers. What should I store in the map instead? The Node object itself?

Comment: Not an error, but something to think about: You are storing `VALUE`s in two places. What happens if those disagree?

Comment: Currently I am using `vNode = new Node(v, nullptr, nullptr)` and the Map now stores `Node` instead of `Node*`. However, when I call addEdge for a previously added node (i.e. adding 2->4 after adding 1->2), my implementation calls `vNode = &nodes.at(v)` to retrieve it from the Map.

However, when I update `vNode.next` to the new node, this information doesn't seem to be cascaded to 1, i.e. 1->next->next is still pointing to a nullptr, while 2->next is pointing to the Node wrapping around 3.

I've added the updated `addEdge` to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial `addEdge` was taking the address of unnamed temporary objects, which is not valid C++.

Your updated `addEdge` has nodes point to the leaked `Node`s that you `new`, not the `Node`s that are in the map.

You don't have to test for presence in the map, `map::emplace` doesn't overwrite existing items, and the return value holds a reference to the `Node` with that key.

```
struct Node {
    VALUE value;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
};

class Graph {
    std::map<VALUE, Node> nodes;
public:
    void addEdge(VALUE u, VALUE v);
};

void Graph::addEdge(VALUE u, VALUE v) {
    Node & uNode = nodes.emplace(u, { u }).first->second;
    Node & vNode = nodes.emplace(v, { v }).first->second;
    uNode.next = &vNode;
    vNode.prev = &uNode;
}
```